# Google Maps V3 custom tooltip

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can I show a nice graphoc tooltip on markers for my Google Maps generated using v3 API?

I've found many examples but only for v2....

Answer (score 1):

For version 3 you can use  [Google Maps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I've used simple DOM manipulation... Here's an article detailing my approach
“Custom tooltips for Google Maps in pure Javascript” @asimmittal https://medium.com/@asimmittal/custom-tooltips-for-google-maps-in-pure-javascript-a8004b8e9458